# Spring Cloud Gateway: Rate Limiting by parsing body

Tags: rate-limiting, spring-cloud-gateway

We've been using Spring Cloud Gateway for about 2 years in production. We're in the process of adding rate limiting support but we've run into a road block. One of the key endpoints we want to rate limit is our `/oauth2/token` endpoint. The trick here is this endpoint has credentials contained in the body that we need for our KeyResolver (to determine alleged identity). So we implemented the following KeyResolver:

```
public class OAuth2KeyResolver implements KeyResolver {
    @Override
    public Mono<String> resolve(ServerWebExchange exchange) {
        String ipAddress = exchange.getRequest().getRemoteAddress().getHostName();

        ServerRequest serverRequest = ServerRequest.create(exchange, 
            HandlerStrategies.withDefaults().messageReaders());

        return serverRequest.bodyToMono(String.class).flatMap(requestBody -> {
            JsonNode json = jackson.readTree(requestBody);
            String clientId = json.path("clientId").asText(null);
            return clientId != null ?
                Mono.just(String.format("%s/%s", ipAddress, clientId) : 
                Mono.empty();
        });
    }
}
```

This works great to read the body and produce the desired key. However we quickly discovered that doing this consumes the body from the `DataBuffer` contained within the `ServerHttpRequest`. This seems to leave Spring Cloud Gateway unable to send the request to the downstream auth service.

Given the interface of this class, I don't think I can mutate the exchange instance to return the contents to the buffer.

How can I safely parse the body here?